# Count how many children are contained inside a specific element

Tags: c#, xml

I want to count how many childs are contained inside the HomeTeam element.This number is dynamic.
I use this ,but gives me how many times HomeTeam is shown.gives me 1

```
int cout = xmlDoc.Descendants("HomeTeam").Count();
```

my XML :

```
<HomeStats>
    <HomeTeam>
        <HomeTeamName>PAN</HomeTeamName>
        <IPERIOD>74</IPERIOD>
        <IIPERIOD>102</IIPERIOD>
        <IIIPERIOD>124</IIIPERIOD>
    </HomeTeam>
</HomeStats>
```

the answer in this example is:The HomeTeam element contains 4 (HomeTeamName,IPERIOD,IIPERIOD,IIIPERIOD).So I must get 4.
Any suggestion?

Comment: And if there are two "HomeTeam" elements, each with differing numbers of children, what do you want to get?  The number of children in the first one, the last one, do you want to get an exception, the sum of both, a random one, or what?

Comment: In my project "HomeTeam" is always 1.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. You just need to add one more step; get the child elements:

```
int cout = xmlDoc.Element("HomeTeam").Elements().Count();
```